# ASP.NET Core mock HttpClient with custom HttpClientHandler

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq, dotnet-httpclient

I have trouble mocking with `Moq`.
Normally having a `HttpClient` I would mock it by injecting the `HttpClient` in the base class like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private readonly HttpClient httpClient;

    public MyClass(HttpClient httpClient)
    {
        this.httpClient = httpClient;
    }
}
```

But now I have different functions in my class `MyClass` that need a custom `HttpClientHandler` like this:

```
HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
...
using var client = new HttpClient(httpClientHandler);
```

If I'd simply inject a `HttpClient` in `MyClassTest` with `var service = new MyClass(httpMock.Object);`, then the httpClient would be overwritten.

What would be the right way to test my functions and not making a real HTTP-call?

Comment: You should look in to `IHttpClientFactory` and typed/named `HttpClient` injection.

Comment: 1) Create a test-only overload where you can pass in a custom handler.  I've used this approach with great success for years.  2) Abstract the class to an HttpClient and inject that instead.  In theory your abstractions should be designed to interfaces and you can hide the fact they even use HTTP.

Comment: I went with `public MyClass(HttpClientHandler httpClientHandler = null)` and then called it with a mock: `var mockHttpMessageHandler = new Mock<HttpClientHandler>();`. It does the job, I'm just not sure, how "clean" or "best practice" it is.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are using [typed client](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/architecture/microservices/implement-resilient-applications/use-httpclientfactory-to-implement-resilient-http-requests) approach of the `IHttpClientFactory`. That's why your `MyClass` ctor receives an `HttpClient` instance.

If you need to mock that `HttpClient` then I suggest you to follow [Hamid Mosalla's advice](https://hamidmosalla.com/2017/02/08/mock-httpclient-using-httpmessagehandler/).

In short there is a helper class, which makes `HttpMessageHandler`'s `SendAsync` mockable (without the need to use the **Moq.Protected**).

```cs
public class FakeHandler: HttpMessageHandler
{
    public virtual HttpResponseMessage Send(HttpRequestMessage request)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected override Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(Send(request));
    }
}
```

You can use this helper class like this to mock any `HttpClient` call:

```cs
var httpResponse = new HttpResponseMessage
{
    Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(responseObject))
};

var mockHandler = new Mock<FakeHandler> { CallBase = true };
mockHandler
    .Setup(handler => handler.Send(It.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>()))
    .Returns(httpResponse);

var mockHttpClient = new HttpClient(mockHandler.Object);
var SUT = new MyClass(mockHttpClient);
```

Comment: This is the same approach that @Andy suggested. I'll definitely have a look into this, when I have more time as this seems more "clean".

Answer (score 1):

> What would be the right way to test my functions and not making a real HTTP-call?

Maybe not what you are looking for, but I suggest you consider Andrew Lock's wisdom - [don't unit-test API/MVC controllers in ASP.NET Core](https://andrewlock.net/should-you-unit-test-controllers-in-aspnetcore/).

For .NET Core (and .NET 5) you should avoid mocking HttpClient if you are testing a controller class.

If a controller class is not your SUT, I would wrap the HttpClient in a facade interface and mock that.

Comment: Well I am testing the underlying Service Class to the Controller. Like fetching and processing data from another page. The result is then given to the Controller. The controller itself is tested against the mocked interface of the Service Layer.
The Service Class should be tested in my opinion and to do that I need the `HttpClient`-mock