# Using Moq to test HttpClient RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync

Tags: c#, http, moq, dotnet-httpclient, identitymodel

I am trying to mock an Http Client that uses the IdentityModel extension to request a client credentials token.

```
var tokenResponse = await _httpClient.RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync(requestContent);
```

I started doing the setup with:

```
var httpClient = new Mock<HttpClient>();


var httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    Content = JsonContent.Create(new
    {
        access_token = "token",
        expires_in = 5000
    })
};

var tokenResponse = ProtocolResponse.FromHttpResponseAsync<TokenResponse>(httpResponseMessage);

httpClient.Setup(x => x.RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync(It.IsAny<ClientCredentialsTokenRequest>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).Returns(tokenResponse);
```

But i end up with:

> System.NotSupportedException : Unsupported expression: x => x.RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync(It.IsAny(), It.IsAny())
> Extension methods (here: HttpClientTokenRequestExtensions.RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.

How can i mock the `RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync` extension?

Comment: You should not mock `HttpClient` rather the underlying `HttpMessageHandler`, please check this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64828596/asp-net-core-mock-httpclient-with-custom-httpclienthandler

Comment: Also please bear in mind that moq is not suitable for mocking `static` methods and extension methods are indeed `static`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the internals of RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync we can see that the base request it is using is SendAsync, so we need to mock SendAsync.

Extension call:

```
response = await client.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait();
```

Final Setup:

```
var httpClient = new Mock<HttpClient>();

var httpResponseMessage = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
    Content = JsonContent.Create(new
    {
        access_token = "token",
        expires_in = 5000
    })
};

httpClient.Setup(x => x.SendAsync(It.IsAny<HttpRequestMessage>(), It.IsAny<CancellationToken>())).Returns(Task.FromResult(httpResponseMessage));
```

Result:
[image: result]